# Serving Static Files with a HTTP 500 Status

Tags: go

Is there a way to serve static files over HTTP in Go with a custom status code (without re-writing a significant amount of private code)?

From what I can see:

1. [http.ServeFile](http://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L426) calls the helper function [http.serveFile](http://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L343)
2. It then calls [http.ServeContent](http://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L117) after determining the mod time and size of the file/dir (and if it exists)
3. Finally, [http.serveContent](http://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L142) is called, which sets the correct headers (Content-Type, Content-Length) and sets a `http.StatusOK` header [here](http://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L254).

I think I already know the answer for this, but if someone has an alternative solution it'd be useful.

The use case is serving 500.html, 404.html, et. al files. I'd normally use nginx to catch Go's usual plain `http.Error` responses and have nginx serve the file off disk, but I'm in an environment where that's not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap `http.ResponseWriter`:

```
type MyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    code int
}

func (m MyResponseWriter) WriteHeader(int) {
    m.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(m.code)
}
```

And then (for an HTTP 500):

```
http.ServeFile(MyResponseWriter{rw, 500}, rq, "file.name")
```

Where `rw` is the "actual" `http.ResponseWriter` and `rq` is the `*http.Request` object.

Comment: Nice, simple and clean. +1

Comment: Perfect—I'd completely forgotten I could do this as an interim measure (and pretty good alternative). Thanks muchly.

Comment: One caveat specific to `http.ResponseWriter` wrapping is the way that "optional" ResponseWriter interfaces (`http.Flusher`, `http.CloseNotifier`, `http.Hijacker`) are handled means that if you just do simple wrapping you'll lose those "optional" features of the original writer (`rw` here). Often that's not an issue but it is something to be aware of.